# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis

I am trying to add Redis to my website for session management but I get the below error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed
```

Below is my code:

I have kept only the relevant redis lines to avoid verbosity.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const connectRedis = require('connect-redis');

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
})

redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
redisClient.on('connect', function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
});

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: 'secret$%^134',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
        httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie 
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 // session max age in miliseconds
    }
}))


app.use(
  session({
    name: 'AuthCookie',
  secret: 'some secret string!',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("We've now got a server!");
  console.log('Your routes will be running on http://localhost:3000');  
});
```

I read that I should add await client.connect() but I am not sure

Comment: which version of node-redis are you using (`npm ls redis`)? because `connect-redis` does not support v4.0.0 at the moment

Comment: Yea I think that is the problem, it works fine with older versions of node and express for some reason